# Calling methods from another class

Tags: ios, delegates, call

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:  (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  facebook = [[Facebook alloc] initWithAppId:@"xxx" andDelegate:self];
}
```

I declared Facebook in my `AppViewDelegate`. I want use this Facebook class from my `UIViewController` or another class. I searched `sharedApplication` title but i didn't that.

Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Could you rephrase your question? It's difficult to understand what you're asking here.

Comment: Sorry. I edited. I hope I explained.

Comment: You can set optional delegate method similar to this SO question.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7703887/ios-class-instance-null/7704174#7704174

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to get it by doing:

```
[(AppViewDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] facebook];
```

I put the cast to AppViewDelegate assuming that is the name of your AppDelegate. However, the problem with this is that you normally don't want to reference your AppDelegate from another class to use it as a class that holds a global variable.

What I would do in this situation is to use a Singleton pattern for Facebook class. Check this link [Singleton Pattern](http://www.johnwordsworth.com/2010/04/iphone-code-snippet-the-singleton-pattern/)